# Concatenate int and string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

How can I concatenate an `int` (e.g: `4`) and a string (e.g: `@"/12"`) for printing?

I'm okay with casting the `int` it to an `NSString` format, but I don't know how I can add `@"/12"` after the int's value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't get your question, but I think you mean something like this:

```
...[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/12", intValue]
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i want.