# NSString and int concatenation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, string-concatenation

I would like to concatenate a string and a `double` (or in this case concatenate a `#define`d constant).
I want to insert the `CURRENT_LATITUDE` and `CURRENT_LONGITUDE` values into the `NSURL` that I'm creating with `URLWithString:`

```
    #define CURRENT_LATITUDE 37.000000
    #define CURRENT_LONGITUDE -120.000000

    NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + CURRENT_LATITUDE + "," + CURRENT_LONGITUDE + "@f&radius=100&sensor=true&types=establishment&key=blahAPIkey123"];
```

I know the `+` signs don't work, so please help me understand how to do this. In Lua you can use

```
.. CURRENT_LATITUDE ..
```

So what should I use in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i concatenate INT and STRING Value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884367/how-do-i-concatenate-int-and-string-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use NSString's `stringWithFormat` method, which works exactly like printf, it looks for format specifiers in the first argument, and then one extra argument per specifier.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%g,%g@f&radius=100&sensor=true&types=establishment&key=blahAPIkey123", CURRENT_LATITUDE, CURRENT_LONGITUDE];
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: The %g are from the C language features which are always available to us in Objective-C. The @f is yours. They are from the famous printf and similar functions, which combine a string and some variables, and they use flags like that to specify what to expect in the variables. %g specifies that the parser should expect a double. Each specifier is paired with an additional argument of that type after the string. Example: `double pi = 3.14`; [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pi is %g", pi];` creates a string as "pi is 3.14".